# System.IO.File.Delete throws Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, delete-file

I have this weird error. When I call `System.IO.File.Delete()`, it throws

> JobCleaner.CleanFiles(): Unable to delete file: D:\WorkerData\4\Run128\Run_TEMPLATE_Rail_Scenario_Type35_INFHD2_NO_TAX_NOMEP\out‌​put_panels\FileIndex55.bin
>
> Error: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

There is no stack trace.

Here is my code:

```
foreach (string strFile in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(strFolder))
{
    try { System.IO.File.Delete(strFile); }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Exception here
        AddToLog("JobCleaner.CleanFiles(): Error occurred when trying to delete file \"" + strFile + "\".\nError:\n" + ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any idea? I tried everything, I check the security on the folder. I enabled "Everyone" with full controls, but still encounter this "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow" exception.

Can anyone help, please? I am using Windows 2012 R2 Datacenter to run my application.

Comment: File.Delete() cannot directly throw this exception, so something else is causing it, the delete doesn't actually work I assume?

Comment: Yes, it's weird. `File.Delete()` has no reason to do any arithmetic operations, never mind throw an exception related to one. It's weird enough that the fact that you didn't post a good question is particularly vexing. You should at a minimum post the complete error information, including stack trace. And really, you should create a better, complete, concise code example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes, it is weird. That is the only line of code that throws the exception. There is no other code apart from System.IO.File.Delete()... I am tearing my hair out :(

Comment: Peter, that is I get from the log file. Here is the complete error (well no stack error):
JobCleaner.CleanFiles(): Unable to delete file: D:\WorkerData\4\Run128\Run_TEMPLATE_Rail_Scenario_Type35_INFHD2_NO_TAX_NOMEP\output_panels\FileIndex55.bin
Error:
Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Ok, I will try to modify my code to output stack trace. Sorry about that...

PS. It works on Windows 7 and Windows 2008. It just doesn't work on Windows 2012 R2 Datacenter

Comment: Log the *entire* exception, including the stack trace. So rather than `ex.Message`, use `ex.ToString()`. The stack trace should tell you exactly what line the error occurred on.

Comment: Grant! Good pickup!!! hahaha... :"> I look at a wrong code. thanks mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't expect it to throw an arithmetic exception, but I have observed some weird behavior when you modify an IEnumerable within the foreach that is walking it. Try moving the file listing out of the loop, like this:

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(strFolder);
foreach (string strFile in files)
{
  try { System.IO.File.Delete(strFile); }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    //Exception here
    AddToLog("JobCleaner.CleanFiles(): Error occurred when trying to delete file \"" + strFile + "\".\nError:\n" + ex.Message);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Moving the call to `GetFiles` won't make any difference. It compiles to the same code as the original.

Comment: I moved GetFiles() out of foreach...loop when modifying my code to output exception (by using ex.ToString()). Now it worked! I, then moved it back to original position, it still worked. I have no idea what is going on. I will try it on other machines.